# How to output a changing message within a for loop in CAPL Script

Tags: vector, capl, canoe

I would like to output using the message name that is stored within a string which changes throughout my for loop. When I place the string as the parameter within my output function, I am throwing an error.

I expected this to work fine, and I am wondering if it could be a type cast from my string into another datatype in order to be accepted as a valid parameter. I am assuming it needs to be of type message, but I am wondering how to get these to work the same. I currently have messages defined as the same names as the string containing the message names.

For example it looks like:

```
on timer F{
  
        for (i = 1; i <= floodingInput; i++)
        {     
          snprintf(msgIterationString, elcount(msgIterationString), "TEST_MSG_%d", i);
          write("%s", msgIterationString);
          output(msgIterationString);
        }
```

The output in the log is:

```
TEST_MSG_1
```

```
TEST_MSG_2
```

And so on and so forth as the loop as defined.